# Remove Header and Footer to add new extra page

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

I',m using Laravel 5.5 to create a PDF file using barryvdh/laravel-snappy.

I want to generate a PDF with and extra page without header and footer. It is to print terms and conditions at the end of my budget.

I can generate the first 2 page with the products , price, header , footer... but when I add the terms and contiditons I have the footer and header and the pdf options ( marging...)

I have tried to remove header and footer using javascript when I loadView removing header and footer with css but I have a white space in those places but I need all the page.

```
    $presupuesto = ExpedientePresupuesto::findOrFail($id_presupuesto);
    $now = Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid');
    $header     = \View::make('expedientes.pdf.cabeceraPresupuesto', compact('now', 'request', 'presupuesto') )->render();
    $footerHTML = Footer::footerHtml($now);
    $footer     = \View::make('expedientes.pdf.piePresupuesto', compact( 'footerHTML', 'request', 'presupuesto') )->render();
    $pdf= \PDF::loadView('expedientes.pdf.cuerpoPresupuesto', compact('presupuesto', 'request'));
   return view('expedientes.pdf.cabeceraPresupuesto', compact('now', 'presupuesto', 'request'));
$pdf->setPaper('a4');
    $pdf->setOption('header-html', $header );
    $pdf->setOption('footer-html', $footer );
    $pdf->setOption('footer-spacing', 10 );
```

My question is it possible to add other page with differents optios in the same PDF? I mean, the first part of the PDF has header footer and anything I want and the last part has no header, other spacing...
Somenting like that ( does not working)

```
   $pdf.= \PDF::loadView('expedientes.pdf.terms', compact('presupuesto', 'request'));
   $pdf->setPaper('a4');
   $pdf->setOption('header-html', '' );
   $pdf->setOption('footer-html',  '');
   $pdf->setOption('footer-spacing', 10 );
   return $pdf->stream( $now . '-PresupuestoFP.pdf');
```

Comment: Can you post your header or/and footer html?

Comment: Are you tried with javascript set to `display:none` your footer/header container element?

Comment: Yes I did , and I get white empty space.

Comment: the header it is a <table> with different tr and td and de footer is inside <page_footer> tag